# type hints for the result of a (<-)

Tags: haskell, io

I find adding type hints useful for debugging, but I don't know how to do that with the result of using `<-` on and IO action

```
action :: IO ()
    foo :: String --doesnt't compile
    foo <- getLine
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do that because <- isn't a declaration. You can either:

```
action :: IO ()
action = do
    foo <- getLine :: IO String
    ...
```

Or, with `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`:

```
action :: IO ()
action = do
    foo :: String <- getLine
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

With `-XScopedTypeVariables`, you can have `(foo :: String) <- getLine`.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness I would like to add

```
action :: IO ()
action = do
  foo <- getLine
  let bar :: String 
      bar = foo
  print bar
```

Which is clunky, but [can be useful](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana/doc/examples/SlotMachine.hs) if you find yourself trapped in the IO monad, which can happen if you're programming a GUI.